# Get width of element of auto width

Tags: c#, wpf, width

I am trying to get the `Width` of a `StackPanel`. I tried:

```
double width = stk_main.ActualWidth;
```

which gave zero and it shouldnt be. Also:

```
double width = stk_main.Width;
```

which gives NaN because width set to auto previously. So how can I get the width?

Comment: `ActualWidth` *should* return the actual width. Where are you making this call? It could be that the stack panel hasn't been fully rendered yet.

Comment: I call it at the end of button click. I see the stack panel and ofcourse its width but it gives width as zero. It gives value when I click button second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sizeChanged, but it doesn't work when the stack panel you used not change size.

```
private void stk_main_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double yourWidthNow = e.NewSize.Width;
}
```

Hope it can give you some help...

Answer (score 0):

You could attach to the `Loaded` event of the `StackPanel` as the layout pass will have completed by this point and the `ActualWidth` will be set.