# Can't get the width of a control when the width is set to auto in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

When I try to get the width of a button or a stack panel when the width is auto, there are two cases:

- when I use `ActualWidth` I always get zero
- when I use `Width` I always get NaN

any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: After searching, this helped me:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11822519/1233659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Width` will always be NaN if you have set it to Auto in XAML.
`ActualWidth` varies depending on the layout state.

During a layout update, the actualwidth of your element may be updated a number of times, and the LayoutUpdated event will be raised repeatedly.

However, if you handle the `SizeChanged` event of the element, this should fire when the layout update has finished, then `ActualWidth` of the element should be accurate.